# No HTTP requests for certain controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently reading a book about ASP.NET MVC3 to learn working with this framework. The concept of partial views is explained and altough it's an easy concept, I have a small question with it.

This razor code is added to the view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Summary", "Cart"); }
```

This calls the Summary()-method on the CartController. The problem is: as a user, I can call this method via a HTTP request (GET/POST,...) what shouldn't be possible.

I know there are attributes like `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` to permit only certain sorts of HTTP requests, but is there also an attribute to prevent these? Also, where can I find a list of available attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a partial view, you are right that it has to be a public method but it should not be addressable on its own. to achive this you can decorate the action method with the `[ChildActionOnly]`

See this for details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx

And for a list of similar attributes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.aspx